Camunda File Picker Not Working in Camunda Forms: "Form failure: form field of type <filepicker> not supported"
Problem:
I'm currently working with Camunda 7 (Community Edition) and Spring Boot for an approval workflow. I've integrated Camunda's inbuilt forms in my project and everything works fine with standard form components like text fields, checkboxes, and date pickers. However, when I attempt to use the File Picker component from Camunda forms, I face the following issue:
The form loads successfully when it doesn't include the file picker component.
When I add the File Picker component, the form fails to load with the following error in the Camunda Tasklist UI:
Form failure: form field of type <filepicker> not supported 
I've tried multiple approaches to troubleshoot this issue, but it persists.[File PickerError](https://i.sstatic.net/TdUKBMJj.png)
Could you please help me on this.

What am I missing in configuring the file picker component?
Is there any specific configuration or dependency required to enable file picker support in embedded forms?

